# im trying to use a command where a repeating command block teleports someone to a spot but my command doesnt work

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was looking for a command and I found this:

```
/execute @a[x=a,y=b,z=c,r=d] ~ ~ ~ tp @p e f g
```

Where:

- `a`, `b`, and `c` are the XYZ coordinates that you want to teleport players from.
- `d` is the radius in blocks around that point where players will be selected (min 1)
- `e`, `f`, and `g` are the XYZ co-ordinates that you want to teleport players to (i.e. the destination)

My command turned out to be:

```
execute @a[-122,4,-74,999] ~ ~ ~ tp @-124 27 -74
```

It doesn't work and I don't know why.

Comment: It seems you are only using three parameters where the example shows four, namely p, e, f, and g (or @p is simply missing). Could that cause the problem?

Comment: What do you mean it “doesn’t work”? Are you receiving an error? Are you not receiving a desired output? Please edit your post to include this information.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the command you found is outdated. It is for pre-1.13 versions of Minecraft.

Secondly, the simplest usage to teleport someone to a spot would be this:

```
tp Steve -124 27 -74
```

It seems that this is a working solution to your problem.

To only teleport a player's inside the coordinate `122 4 999`, use:

```
tp @a[x=-122,y=4,z=999,dx=0] -124 27 -74
```

Comment: i want to tp some one if they touch a certain y position with command blocks automaticly

Comment: I edited my answer. Could you please clarify your question?